# I am working on a web scraper lab for my assignment

Tags: python

This is the coding I am working for;

```
filename = "hp_products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "price, product\n"

f.write(headers)

containers = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"product-item-link"})

for i in range(0, len(containers)):

    price_container = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"price"})
    price = price_container[i].text.strip()

    product_container = soup.findAll("strong", {"class":"product name product-item-name"})
    product = product_container[i].text

    print ("price: ", price)
    print ("product: ", product)

    f.write(str(price.replace(",", "")) + "," + str(product) + "\n")

f.close()
```

There is an output but also an error.

Error message;

[image]

So what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that index `i` at some point is equal or greater than `len(price_container)`

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, extract a [mcve] to include in your question, along with both the expected and actual output it produce. That said, don't use images of text! Those can't be searched, like e.g. when researching what an error means and what might cause it (which goes on your to-do list as well).

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the length of `containers` is greater than the length of `price_container`. These are two different lists and if they are not guaranteed to be of equal length (which appears to be the case here), you cannot iterate over the length of one and expect to have a value at each index.

It looks like you are trying to find a `price_container` inside each `container` so you probably need to update

```
price_container = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"price"})
```

so that it gets all spans with the class "price" from `containers[i]` rather than using `soup.findAll()` on your base html. Since it appears there are fewer `price_containers` than `containers`, you may need to check that the current container actually has a price.